# Java Metro Security: StreamMessage has been already consumed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I'm using metro 2.0.1 for a client application who connects to WCF Service With security. Everything works fine in my unit tests but when I call the method in my Java application I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: StreamMessage has been already consumed. See the nested exception for where it's consumed
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.unconsumed(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:512)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:251)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.create(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:536)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:118)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
 at $Proxy42.getGiftvoucherBalance(Unknown Source)
 at com.rs.sw.fs.service.jaxws.account.card.JaxWsGiftVoucherService.getBalance(JaxWsGiftVoucherService.java:245)
 at com.rs.sw.fs.application.SkyllaApplication.main(SkyllaApplication.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.unconsumed(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:516)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.writePayloadTo(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:375)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.writeTo(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:493)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.readAsSOAPMessage(AbstractMessageImpl.java:193)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.VerifiedStreamMessage.readAsSOAPMessage(VerifiedStreamMessage.java:474)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.PolicyResolverImpl.resolvePolicy(PolicyResolverImpl.java:151)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.createMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:894)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:232)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.verifyInboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:486)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientResponsePacket(SecurityClientTube.java:405)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processResponse(SecurityClientTube.java:338)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:639)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
 ... 5 more
```

I guess there's a difference between my classpath in junit and my Java application (running eclipse and maven)

In case someone is interested here's our huge dependency tree:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] eres.fs:fs-std:jar:3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- eres.fs:fs-core:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:1.2b7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- jgoodies:forms:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |  +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.1-407.jdbc3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-remoting:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlbeans:xbean:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-aegis:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20040917:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-java5:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-spring:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile (version managed from 1.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile (version managed from 1.3)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-xmlbeans:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons:XmlSchema:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:barcode:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:djester:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:I18N:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:log:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:util:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jclark:xt:jar:20020507:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jclark:xp:jar:19990102:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:reporting:jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.commons:set-expressions:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.fs:fs-ebo-dao:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.fs:skylla-theme:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.fs:fashion-theme:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.javapos:jpos-core:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.linuxnet:jpcsc:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- gnu.io:RXTXcomm:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.serialio:Serialio:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.javapos:jpos:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:test (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.javapos:jcl_editor:jar:2.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.javapos:POSTest:jar:1.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.comm:comm:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.serialio:JavaTerm:jar:5.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.retail-logic:SolveLink:jar:1.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jp.co.nec.jpos:tw5500jpos:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.messagebus:ebo-javaobject:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- eres.messagebus:ebo-javaobjectAPIs:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.messagebus:gateway:jar:4.0.2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- sonic:sonic_Crypto:jar:6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- sonic:sonic_Selector:jar:6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- sonic:sonic_Client:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- sonic:sonic_SF:jar:6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- gnu:gnu-regexp:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.messagebus:jebo-listener:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- eres.messagebus:ebo-marshaller:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- eres.messagebus:ebo-jibx-marshaller:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.services:services-client:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.services:waitticket-service:jar:3.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.fs:remote-control:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.ws:webservices-rt:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.xml:webservices-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.services:customer-service-client:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- eres.services:service-client-commons:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.services:loyalty-service-client:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.services:notification-service-client:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- eres.fs.promopack:promopackAPIs:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.commons:commons-util:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.domain:fs-domain-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.domain:fs-domain-article:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.domain:fs-domain-account:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.repository:fs-repository-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.data:fs-data-api:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.repository:fs-repository-skylla:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.data:fs-data-jdbc:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.data:fs-data-service:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.domain:fs-domain-service:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.service:fs-service-api:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.rs.sw.fs.framework:fs-test:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.1:test (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  |     \- com.rs.sw.commons:commons-test:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework:fs-view:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.data:fs-data-gateway:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.service:fs-service-jaxws:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rs.sw.fs.framework.service:fs-service-jaxws-giftvoucher:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.rs.sw.commons:commons-jaxws:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- eres.commons:launcher:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO]    \- eres.commons:system-util-native:dll:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]       \- eres.commons:system-util:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

Comment: Hey Stijn, did you ever get the solution for this problem? I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: It was a long time ago but I can advise you to never use metro together with cxf or any other ws implementation and use m2eclipse it uses the order of your pom to setup the classpath otherwise your classpath order is randomly chosen

Answer (score 0):

After bumping into the same issue and spending about a day chasing for class loading order (metro, cxf) I did not get anywhere.

Looking into my JVM parameters and the way it was launched I noticed "-ea" (enable assertions). Disabling assertions by removing "-ea" apparently solves this issue.

Comment: Then you can't use assertions anywhere in your own code and you'll need to be sure that the JVM parameters are in your control.